# typescript infer and narrow down element of Array

Tags: typescript

```
type elementOf<T extends unknown[]>=T extends (infer A)[]? A : never

const a = ['abc']

type resultA = elementOf<typeof a> //string
```

I need to infer the literal type of array element, but it doesn't work

const assertion or type notation did the trick

```
const b:'abc'[] = ['abc' as const]

type resultB = elementOf<typeof b> // 'abc'
```

however is it possible to do it **without** const assertion or type annotation?

Comment: This is not possible at this time; type annotation or const assertion is needed.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is not possible with arrays without casting `as const`, but could you use tuples?

Comment: you don't need type annotation and const assertion together. you can write `const b = ['abc' as const]` or `const b:'abc'[] = ['abc']`

Comment: Your `elementOf` type here could simply be `T[number]`. No fancy `infer` keyword required.